# Getting the content of a view Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, view, rcp, workbench

How can I get the content of a specific view ? For instance, I want to get the size of a table in a view. I only have the view ID wanted and more globally the workbench. I cannot modify the original RCP project.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage.findView(String)* to return the IViewPart (the instance of the contributed object that created that view).  From there, you would have to know and have access to the class and internals to get ahold of their Tree object:

```
IViewPart part = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
    .findView(MyView.ID);
if (part instanceof MyView) {
    MyView view = (MyView) part;
    // now access whatever internals you can get to
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer, it's running fine :)