# How to access the view of another plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, view, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin / extension of another plugin. For this I need to access the information displayed in a view by the other plugin.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I've only found how to do this if the view I want to access is created by the plugin I am currently developing

(using workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView(MyView.ID);)

but this doesn't seem to be suitable in my situation as I do not know the ID of the view and do not have the MyView object.

Edit: The view contains a table with Strings / ints which I need. I guess it's also important to note that I have parts the source code of the other plugin available, so the class of the view.

Edit2: Because I have the source code of the other plugin, I was able to solve this - see comments.

Comment: What information do you want? The current selection is usually easy to get, anything else is probably not possible.

Comment: It contains a table with Strings / ints. I need those.

Comment: If you have the source code you should be able to find the view id (in the plugin.xml). The rest of the answer depends on reading that source code to see if the plugin provides a way to access its data.

Comment: Hey, thank you so far. I was trying to use the approach posted as an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151277/getting-the-content-of-a-view-eclipse-rcp

I found the ID in the plugin.xml, so I now have .... findView("string_from_plugin_xml"). But I do not know what to do with the MyView objects, may you help me out there?

Comment: Yes, I know. That answer requires you to do exactly what I said. You have to look at the source code (in that answer 'MyView') and work out if it provides any way to access what you want.

Comment: I guess I got it now. I had to add the class which implements this view in the other plugin to my manifest, then import it and replace MyView with it. Now I can access the methods to get my info. Thank you very much for your help!